# Is this possible to pay through paypal account instead of credit card without leaving site?

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway

is this possible to pay through paypal account instead of credit card without leaving site using magento 1.8 version?

Comment: Paypal requires all payments to be done on their own window. So, probably no.

Comment: Yes, use paypal hosted pro method. This is available in enterprise edition.

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR, do we anything for community version?

Comment: @Ram, I don't know. But we can customize that by creating new payment method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can do it with **"Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution Integration"**

You can find guide how to do it [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf)